# Research strategy to Ship - A new approach

Tags: discussion

[Loop #1 - This change in approach](https://stackoverflow.blog/2019/12/11/the-loop-1-how-we-conduct-research-on-the-community-team/) is interesting & looks healthy, only thing concerning is lean chance for Meta feedback. Want to see how people take it here.

**Past:**

> [image]

**Present & Future:**

> [image]

Comment: This has already been addressed [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/340164/please-consider-gathering-meta-feedback-before-the-ship-stage).

Comment: wow, very fast. I searched for loop keyword, could not find this in my initial search, thanks.

Comment: Meta feedback after ship has sailed == we are not interested in feedback